# Small app to show variables declared in a bash script

Tags: bash, jq

This code and updates are available on [Github](https://github.com/harleypig/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/showvars).

I've written a small utility to dump the variables that are assigned in a bash script.

Please note:

- This script depends on the shfmt and jq apps.
- I am not looking to make this script posix compliant, only bash specific.

Some possible areas for improvement:

- Can the jq query be improved?
- Are there other entries in the json output of shfmt that I can look for variable assignments.
- Any gotchas I'm missing?

As I type out this question, it occurs to me that showing variables used in a script would be a good thing to allow as an option. I'll look into it, but if anyone has any ideas in this respect, I'm interested in hearing your input.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

warn() { printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2; }

die() {
  (($#)) && warn "$*"
  exit 1
}

command_exists() { command -v "$1" &> /dev/null; }

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_showvars() {
  local filename=$1
  [[ -f $filename ]] || die "$filename is not a file or does not exist."
  [[ -r $filename ]] || die "$filename is not readable."

  jq_query='[ .. | select(.Assigns?) | .. | select(.Name?) | .Name.Value ] | unique[]'

  # shellcheck disable=SC2046
  printf '  %s\n' $(shfmt -tojson < "$filename" | jq "$jq_query" | tr -d '"')
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(($#)) || {
  cat << EOH

showvars is a simple script that shows
what variables are assigned in a bash
script

usage: showvars filename [filename ...]

EOH

  exit 1
}

for r in shfmt jq; do
  command_exists $r || die This script depends on $r and it is not found.
done

for f in "$@"; do
  printf '\n%s:\n' "$f"
  _showvars "$f"
  shift
done

echo
```

Edit: Fixed copy-paste error with `(($#))...` line
Edit: Removed code that removes lower case variables (an artifact from another code solution)

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The difference between `$*` and `$@`

> ```
> warn() { printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2; }
> ```

This is equivalent to the simpler:

```
warn() { echo "$*" >&2; }
```

The `printf` version is useful if you want to produce one line per parameter,
and in that case you must use `"$@"` instead of `"$*"`.
Also in callers of `warn`.

#### Use `-r` for raw output of `jq`

Instead of `jq "..." | tr -d '"'` a better way is `jq -r "..."`.

#### An alternative to `printf` and a sub-shell

Instead of this:

> ```
>   # shellcheck disable=SC2046
>   printf '  %s\n' $(shfmt -tojson < "$filename" | jq "$jq_query" | tr -d '"')
> ```

I recommend this way (and no need to disable shellcheck):

```
shfmt -tojson < "$filename" | jq -r "$jq_query" | sed -e 's/^/  /'
```

#### Use a bit more double-quotes

You did a good job of double-quoting the most important things.
I would double-quote here too:

> ```
> command_exists $r || die This script depends on $r and it is not found.
> ```

To train good habits:

```
command_exists "$r" || die "This script depends on $r and it is not found."
```

#### `"$@"` is the default list for `for`

Instead of `for f in "$@"; do`, you can simply write `for f; do`.

#### The shebang

In some systems Bash is not in `/bin/bash`.
For that reason I prefer to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the shebang, it makes the script more portable.

#### Simplify the readable file check?

> ```
>   [[ -f $filename ]] || die "$filename is not a file or does not exist."
>   [[ -r $filename ]] || die "$filename is not readable."
> ```

The `-r` implies `-f`. I would simplify this to one line:

```
[[ -r $filename ]] || die "$filename is not a readable file."
```

#### Use `echo` when it's good enough

Instead of `printf '\n%s:\n' "$f"` I would write:

```
echo
echo "$f:"
```

#### Here-documents

`EOH` is an unusual symbol for the here-document marker.
That's not a problem, but I think the less surprising elements in a script,
the better.
I don't see a good reason to not call this `EOF` as usual.

#### Your questions

> Some possible areas for improvement:
>
> - Can the jq query be improved?
> - Are there other entries in the json output of shfmt that I can look for variable assignments.

Unfortunately I'm not able to answer these. 
You might want to wait for another reviewer who can!

Comment: Thank you. I implemented some of your suggestions, while others prompted a different change. I've included details in my question.